# React-native app is crashing without error in android studio

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting these errors ;

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please provide more info for us to help properly. Does this happens when you start your application or in runtime?

Comment: it happens when i start the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up a new tab in the terminal and in your project folder type `react-native-start` and then go back to the other tab and run your project by typing `react-native run-android`

By using react-native start you will see the metro bundler starting up and running. If you want to clear the metro cache then type the below in your project directory

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```